# Missing tools in uv editor

Tags: uv

When i got to uv editors the  "UVS" tab is missing

does anyone know why
[image: When i got to uv editors the "UVS" tab is missing]

Comment: Select the object and go in edit mode and select all and you can find in the UV editor

Answer (score 2):

You have to have an object that has some UV data and be in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue and after looking for useless answers I found some light here - https://blenderartists.org/t/uv-menu-not-visible/440506/10 - the way I fixed that was by going to *Edit Mode*, selecting the object and then on the UV options applied *Reset*. It worked